# Why is Magento only showing 22 products on the front when I have 409 configurable products?

Tags: magento

Im getting incredibly annoyed with my magento website, I have 4900 products 409 of them are configurable products, when I make a category in this case carpets and try and save the 4900 products to that category it makes a duplicate category called the exact same as the previous, now whats confusing is that I dont know how this is happening usually magento panics when it has 2 things the same, both these categories have the exact same ID its incredibly annoying and to top it off its only showing 22 products on the front in the category carpets, any ideas ??

I disabled the theme and just had the default theme to see if that was the problem its not.

You can check out this annoying website at `http://192.163.235.139/carpets.html`

[image]

Comment: OK, I have 4905 products with 409 configurable products all of which have 11 associated products attached, all the configurable products are enabled, all are in stock, all the products are exactly the same only difference is the title, sku, image and price, there is nothing that would stop these products showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, this answer makes no sense whatsoever, but Ive managed to fix it it had something to do with the qty and that all the simple products had nothing for quantity not even 0 so what you had to do was go into the simple product individually and just click save and thats it the products now appear on the page. its the biggest load of crap I have ever seen in my life.

so if your having this issue with your products go into a simple product change nothing and just click save and it works.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue.
In my case it was a frontend bug. It's not possible to have two categories with the same id.
May be upgrade your version.

Comment: Please specify the version in which you can see the bug in addition to a reference where we can see what you're talking about.

Comment: 1.7.0.1
Index mode "Category Products" > manual. helped me before the upgrade